# Strange issue with hibernate entity with mysql 5.6.16

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I am getting one strange issue with hibernate entity and mysql 5.6.16 combination. However I found my solution with trial and error method but didn't get the logic behind it. I didn't get much help on Google too.

I have developed a hibernate application with mysql 5.6.22 and tested the same in my windows system and working fine.

When I deployed the same application into my redhat linux server having mysql 5.6.16 then getting below error even though the user table exists in database

```
2016-02-28 00:52:45 WARN  SqlExceptionHelper:143 - SQL Error: 1146, SQLState: 42S02
2016-02-28 00:52:45 ERROR SqlExceptionHelper:144 - Table '<dbname>.User' doesn't exist
```

The complain form my redhat server that I found was because the hibernate entities which got generated by my eclipses did not add @Table("user") if the table name is "user" but adds @Table("user_address") in the entity if the table name is having an underscore (_).

One more possibility is mysql at redhat server does not support case insensitive table name i.e. hibernate generates query as "select * from User" if @Table("user") is not added explicitly in the entity

My question is how the same code [without addition of @Table("user")] is working in my windows system?

Any logic behind this?

Comment: table names CAN be case sensitive, depending on the underlying file system. `User != user`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have suspected in my problem statement that this issue mainly comes because of the mysql does not support case insensitivity in redhat server but windows does. This issue can be fixed either of the following way in linux.

1. Add **lower_case_table_names = 1** under [mysqld] in my.cnf file and restart the mysql server

OR

2. add @Table("user") in the hibernate entity class